# CSS Hover - Not aplying to certain element

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm quite new to coding and I'm having trouble with the "hover".

It opens already on other parts of the website, but not on the specific location I want. Also it somehow stays opened after hovering and leaving the position. Does someone know why? :)

```css
.pill1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 300px;
  top:10px;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  transition: .5s ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.middle {
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  left: 38%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 100;
}


.container:hover .pill1 {
}

.container:hover .middle {
  opacity: 1;
}

.text {
  background-color: rgba(22, 32, 162, 0.44);
  color: rgba(242, 0, 255, 0.55);
  font-family: Akzidenz-Grotesk Pro, bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
       <img src="images/xanax0001.png" alt="Avatar" class="pill1" >
       <div class="middle">
         <div class="text">"....".</div>
     </div>
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I fully understand. When you run the code snippet, is the problem visible there? You say it opens on other parts of the website. Maybe you have multiple .container cascaded? If yes, maybe try changing your selector to `container:hover > .pill1` and `.container:hover > .middle` ([Child Selector](https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/))

Comment: Please show your full explanation/issue in any way you can, this it not clear enough to really understand. Regards!

Comment: This is not at all clear my friend. In in-built Code snippets running feature of Stack OVerflow, it is working. So maybe you should be a little more descriptive about it.